# Open Source tools to visualise MySQL/MariaDB performance metrics (show global status with interval)

Tags: mysql, performance, mariadb, tools, chart

I'm searching for an Open Source tool to visualise MySQL/MariaDB performance metrics (output of show global status in nice graphs).

In MongoDB world there is the Closed Source Ops Manager and the Open Source [`mtools`](https://github.com/rueckstiess/mtools). I'm searching for something similar.

In official Oracle training for MySQL 5.6 there are diagrams like

[image]

While searching the internet I also found some RRDtool based graphs.

[image]

So my question is how to generate ad hoc nice visualisations from MariaDB performance metrics? Is there some Open Source project which helps in this task? How do other DBAs do this?

Comment: Where did you get those RRDTool based graphs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of choices out there:

- [Percona Monitoring plugins for Zabbix, Cacti, Nagios](https://www.percona.com/software/mysql-tools/percona-monitoring-plugins)
- [Percona Monitoring and Management](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-monitoring-and-management/index.html)
- Monyog
- Severalnines Clustercontrol

Equally capable but not on-premise (afaik) is Vividcortex.

Comment: Out of these, only Percona's tools are open-source. (Also, note that MONyog is now (2019) called "SQL Diagnostic Manager for MySQL".)

Answer (score 1):

Get MonYog through MariaDB.  https://www.webyog.com/product/monyog

Note: anything that works with MySQL, MariaDB, or Percona, will *probably* work well with the others.

I looked at lots of tools, but came away thinking that most graphs were measuring either stuff that never changes.  My favorite tool metric is the number of slowlog entries.  If that goes up, there are problems.  At that point, sometimes the other graphs lead to useful info, but usually fixing a query is the real solution to a performance problem.